# Pset5 - Speller : all words in the text MISSPELLED

Tags: c, dictionary, hashtable, cs50

I've been stuck with this pset for more then a week now and can't seems to get any closer to getting something out of my code. I keep getting all the words in the text misspelled and I really don't understand how to create a hash function myself (I'm guessing the issue mostly comes from this but I'm not sure either...). I wanted to create a hash table with the first two letters of each words (it is inspired from various options I saw online).

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong...

Thanks in advance !

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 676;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Initialize new variables used in the program
unsigned int numberofwords;
unsigned int hashvalue;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // Hash the word to determine its hash value
    hashvalue = hash(word);

    // Set cursor to the head of the linked list of the word
    node* cursor = table[hashvalue];

    // Traverse into the linked list comparing the word to find a correspondance while the cursor isn't pointing to null
    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(cursor->word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // Inittialize a variable to keep track of the total of ASCII values
     unsigned int sum = 0;

    // Loop in all the letters in the word
    for (int i = 0 ; i < strlen(word) ; i++)
    {
        // Ignore digits
        if (word[i] != isalpha(word[i]))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            // Check the first two characters in the word while setting them to lower letters in order to get they ASCII value
            sum += 26 * (tolower(word[0]) - 'a') + (tolower(word[1]) - 'a');
        }
        // Divide the total of the three letters by the number of buckets
        hashvalue = sum % N;
    }
    return hashvalue;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Open the file
    FILE* file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fclose(file);
        perror("Loading error");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // While dictionary doesn't return EOF, read strings from the file, one at the time
        while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
        {
            // Create a new node for the word and copy it in the node
            node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
            if (n == NULL)
            {
                return false;
            }
            strcpy (n->word, "%s");

             // Hash word to obtain a hash value
            hashvalue = hash(word);

            // Insert word into hash table depending if it's the first word or not
            if (table[hashvalue] != NULL)
            {
                n->next = table[hashvalue];
            }
            else
            {
                n->next = NULL;
            }
            table[hashvalue] = n;

            // Add one to the counter
            numberofwords++;
        }
        fclose(file);
        // Return true
        return true;
    }
}



// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // Return the number of words we're keeping track of while loading the dictionary
    return numberofwords;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // Check all the head of the hash table
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        // Create a temporary node to not lose the rest of the linked list
        node* cursor = table[i];

        // Set the cursor to the next node while the temporary value remains at the inital location, then free it before to move to cursor
        while(cursor != NULL)
        {
            node* tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the dictonary.h file :

```
// Declares a dictionary's functionality

#ifndef DICTIONARY_H
#define DICTIONARY_H

#include <stdbool.h>

// Maximum length for a word
// (e.g., pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)
#define LENGTH 45

// Prototypes
bool check(const char *word);
unsigned int hash(const char *word);
bool load(const char *dictionary);
unsigned int size(void);
bool unload(void);

#endif // DICTIONARY_H
```

Comment: `// Loop in all the letters in the word` Why? You only care about `word[0]` and `word[1]`

Comment: `strcpy (n->word, "%s");` You seem to store only that string in each of your nodes, do you? You should copy the newly read `word` instead. I would consider that to be some typo...

Comment: You need to at a minimum include the "dictionary.h" file and any other supporting files so that the community can analyze your code and provide suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ! Really appriciated :) I've change the loop to only check the first two letters (word[1]) and changed string to word but it compiles but it doesnt seems to change the out put.

Comment: You should remove the whole loop. Otherwise you will add the value twice to `sum`.

Comment: THANK YOU !! That was it ! it works perfectly and no other errors after correcting this one !